# jQuery.noty is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I include jquery.noty.js, layouts/top.js, themes/default.js into my page from Noty 2.1.0 and JQuery 1.10.2.
 I use that:

```
noty(text: '!!!');
```

I have this error:

```
TypeError: jQuery.noty is undefined
options.closeWith = jQuery.noty.defaults.closeWith; (jquery.noty.js:479)
```

How to fix what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth,

```
noty(text: '!!!',
    onClose: ->
      ...
  );
```

should be

```
noty(text: '!!!',
    onClose: ()->
      ...
  );
```

Doesn't seem like that will fix your problem though.

Make sure that jquery.noty.js is being loaded BEFORE the coffeescript that you're running

Comment: i use precompiled coffeescript so it's simple js

Comment: Even if it's precompiled, it still matters what order the files are compiled in. If noty is being compiled AFTER the file where you are referring to it, the file referring to it won't be able to see it.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. The reason was that jQuery library was being loaded twice - the second time it was loaded after noty had been already loaded. It caused that $ object with methods added by noty library was overwritten with the new one without those methods.